# Material Ui AppBar with Nprogress

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, progress-bar, next.js

Code:

```
<AppBar color='inherit' position='fixed'><AppBar>
```

I am using material-ui, when I use **nprogress in Nextjs App** with material ui then it not shown in top. But when **AppBar** color is **transparent** then **nprogress bar shown**. Now I need to see nprogress in top of **AppBar (with fixed position and inherit color)** when page transition start.

Comment: Did you update the bar styles from the css? You can place the progress at the top of the AppBar by setting the z-index, on your css file, property to a value greater than 1100, the z-index of the AppBar's MUI component, ie  `z-index: 1110 !important;`. The color can be updated in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

According to [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/z-index/), zIndex of AppBar is 1100, so you could do this way:

```
 <ProgressBar
            options={{showSpinner: false}}
            shallowRouting
            style={`
              #nprogress .bar {
              background: #ffffff;
              position: fixed;
              z-index: 1110 !important;
              top: 0;
              left: 0;
              width: 100%;
              height: 2px;
            }
           `}
        />
```